# Flutter custom page transition - animating old route

Tags: flutter, transition, mobile-application, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation

I want to create custom page transition animation in Flutter. I have two pages/routes:

1. List of radios page (LISTPAGE)
2. Radio detail page (DETAILPAGE)

## **[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ewpowks3Qg) is transition that I need to create.**

Look only to 0:18 seconds.

As I know, Flutter enabled to use `transitionBuilder` inside `PageRouteBuilder` when pushing new route. But how can I animate widgets in LISTPAGE as part of transition to DETAILPAGE? Is it possible?

Flutter have only few transition widgets - **ScaleTransition, SlideTransition, FadeTransition, ...**

### Is it even possible to create something like this?

How would you approach this design?

Comment: @pskink I am able to create animation inside LISTPAGE - slide upper and bottom blue panel and transition white tile to its final position.

But, how can I bake this into transition? I want this nice animation to be a transition effect when pushing to a DETAILPAGE route.

And when calling Navigator.pop(), run a slide transition only.

Comment: ok i see it now, so except `ScaleTransition`, `SlideTransition`, and `FadeTransition` you can also use `AnimatedBuilder` which is driven by any `Listenable animation` - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart for some real examples